# Is Anything wrong in my query .Nest elastic C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Is there something wrong in my .Nest libs query? My query will get all data, I need to get by multi term.
Query string elastic result i want:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1000,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "log_query": {
         "doc_count": 2,
         "histogram_Log": {
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key_as_string": "06/02/2015 12:00:00",
                  "key": 1423180800000,
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key_as_string": "21/02/2015 12:00:00",
                  "key": 1424476800000,
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My query string elastic:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "log_query": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "cluster": "giauht1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "server": "hadoop0"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "Warn"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "actionTime": {
                  "gte": "2015-02-01",
                  "lte": "2015-02-24"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "histogram_Log": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "actionTime",
            "interval": "1d",
            "format": "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My .nest libs query:

```
 Func<SearchDescriptor<LogInfoIndexView>, SearchDescriptor<LogInfoIndexView>> query =
                que => que.Aggregations(aggs => aggs.Filter("log_query", fil =>
                {
                    fil.Filter(fb => fb.Bool(fm => fm.Must(
                        ftm =>
                        {
                            ftm.Term(t => t.Cluster, cluster);
                            ftm.Term(t => t.Server, server);
                            ftm.Term(t => t.Type, logLevel);
                            ftm.Range(r => r.OnField("actionTime").GreaterOrEquals(from.Value).LowerOrEquals(to.Value));
                            return ftm;
                        }))).Aggregations(faggs => faggs.DateHistogram("histogram_Log", dr =>
                    {
                        dr.Field("actionTime");
                        dr.Interval("1d");
                        dr.Format("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
                        return dr;
                    }));
                    return fil;
                })).Size(0).Type(new LogInfoIndexView().TypeName);
            var result = client.Search(query);
```

My .nest result:
[image: .nest result]

[image: .nest result 2]

My model mapping:

```
{
   "onef-sora": {
      "mappings": {
         "FPT.OneF.Api.Log": {
            "properties": {
               "actionTime": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "application": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "cluster": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "detail": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "iD": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "message": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "server": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "source": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "tags": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "typeLog": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "typeName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "url": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "user": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The way I see it is that you have 1000 documents matching the `log_query` filter aggregation and then those 1000 documents are bucketed in 297 daily buckets in the `histogram_Log` aggregation. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: i need my query return 2 documents, let see elastic result in my post, my .nest query wrong, i don't know why.

Comment: my filter get same value my elastic query: cluster: giauht1, server: hadoop0, actionDate from 2015-02-01,to 2015-02-24

Comment: Can you open the `Items` element so we can gain some insight into what buckets you have in there?

Comment: Ok, definitely looks like your aggregation filter is not taken into account, I might know why...

Comment: thank very much, @Val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Must()` condition passed to the `Bool()` filter takes a `params Func<FilterDescriptor<T>, FilterContainer>[]` but in your filter, the `Term()` and `Range()` filters are chained onto the same filter instance; unfortunately, this doesn't work as you *might* expect and the end result is actually an empty json object passed to the `must` clause in the query DSL for the filter i.e. you end up with

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "log_query": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {} /* where are the filters?! */
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "histogram_Log": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "actionTime",
            "interval": "1d",
            "format": "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The solution is to pass an array of `Func<FilterDescriptor<T>, FilterContainer>`; The following matches your query DSL

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connection = new InMemoryConnection(settings);
    var client = new ElasticClient(connection: connection);

    DateTime? from = new DateTime(2015, 2,1);
    DateTime? to = new DateTime(2015, 2, 24);

    var docs = client.Search<LogInfoIndexView>(s => s
        .Size(0)
        .Type("type")
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Filter("log_query", f => f
                .Filter(ff => ff
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(m => m
                            .Term(t => t.Cluster, "giauht1"),
                              m => m
                            .Term(t => t.Server, "hadoop0"),
                              m => m
                            .Term(t => t.Type, "Warn"),
                              m => m
                            .Range(r => r.OnField("actionTime").GreaterOrEquals(from.Value).LowerOrEquals(to.Value))
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Aggregations(aa => aa
                    .DateHistogram("histogram_Log", da => da
                        .Field("actionTime")
                        .Interval("1d")
                        .Format("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(docs.RequestInformation.Request));
}

public class LogInfoIndexView
{
    public string Cluster { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActionTime { get; set; }    
}
```

returning

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "log_query": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "cluster": "giauht1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "server": "hadoop0"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "Warn"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "actionTime": {
                  "lte": "2015-02-24T00:00:00.000",
                  "gte": "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "histogram_Log": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "actionTime",
            "interval": "1d",
            "format": "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In answer to your comment, the difference between a [`filtered query filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) and a [`filter aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) is that the former applies the filtering to all documents at the start of the query phase and filters are generally cached, improving performance on subsequent queries with those filters, whilst the latter applies in the scope of the aggregation to filter documents in the current context to a single bucket. If your query is only to perform the aggregation and you're likely to run the aggregation with the same filters, I think the `filtered query filter` should offer better performance.

Comment: thanks U,i put filters aggregation to query, it's work. what diff between query filter and aggregation filters, which fast?